# Real Colors on Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, adobe-photoshop, colors

I was creating an info graphic in Photoshop when I noticed that the color is quite different between my two monitors:

[image]

Which one is the "real" color? I would expect the answer to that to be neither. So **how can you know which is the color that will be printed on paper? Also, how can you set the monitors (or at least Photoshop) to show the "real" colors?**

Comment: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/

Comment: The *ideal* solution to your problem is to calibrate everything. It's a huge topic, too big for the Q&A nature of SU. Here's some excellent reading on the subject: http://people.rit.edu/med2823/colormanageproject/iccworkflow.html

Answer (score 1):

I would look online for ICC color profiles for your monitor. They can adjust the colors to be more accurate. 

More on color profiles in windows:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-color-management-settings

Comment: That's a start but still won't guarantee what you see on the monitor will be what's printed out on paper. You need to calibrate the whole workflow. Scanner, monitor, and printer (including each type of paper you print on).

Comment: That's definitely true. I totally forgot about the other devices. My bad.

Answer (score -3):

The first comment is correct , your monitor requires calibration.

Alternatively you can purchase a computer with properly calibrated monitor out of the box ( the only manufacturer to do this for the past decade is Apple )

Comment: That's utter rubbish. Apple is not the only manufacturer to produce calibrated monitors out of the box.

Comment: @misha256 can you please name one ? I don't mean a monster which is capable of being calibrated I mean a moniter which is perfectly calibrated to the video card so one can simply plug a machine in, turn it on and work with photoshop.

Comment: ASUS PA248Q, HP Z24x, Samsung S27B970D. These are three that I know of off hand, no doubt there will be others. If you connect via DVI-D/DisplayPort/HDMI then calibration against the video card itself is *not* required. There is no such thing as *perfect* calibration. The three monitors I listed above are well calibrated out-of-the box and support user calibration too (because color will shift over time as with any monitor).

Comment: I had to look these models up, the Asus is calibrated to Delta-E of Less than 5, Samsung seem to 'mass calibrate' (all reports that come out of samsung are identical which isnt possible.) and the HP dosn't even mention what accuricy it was calibrated to. (plus the HP monitor costs the same as a imac of a similar size. )

Comment: Your answer suggested that only Apple pre-calibrates monitors. My comment was to make you aware that there *are* other companies pre-calibrating mointors. As for the quality and accuracy of calibration, that would need to be tested and quantified. However, the fact still remains that Asus, HP, and Samsung all market certain monitors that are pre-calibrated – in addition to Apple. I have used all three monitors myself. All three would serve 99% users who are looking for a *good* level of calibration out of the box. Of the three, that HP monitor is nothing short of stunning thus it's high $-tag.

Comment: My comment was based primarily on the fact that apple for years was the only company which performed calibration on the screens to their devices out of the box for consumer-level hardware ( this is back when you had to not only adjust for the video card but as well as the cable, This is pre-DVI . ), SGi and NeXT did too but if you could afford one of those then you most likely had a calibration device on hand also...

Comment: I get that, and to *some extent* you're right. But now, today, in the year 2015, it is categorically *wrong* to say Apple is the only company pre-calibrating monitors. The last thing we need on a forum designed to help share knowledge is to give people wrong information or mis-represent the truth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21486/discussion-between-misha256-and-damian-nikodem).